# Faster report generation by caching mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, report

I have a mysql database that is in **3NF(Third normal form)**.

The web application is written in JAVA.

The main table "**Events**" has about 1.2 million rows.

The application supports many reports based on the data rows in Events.
Some of the complex **reports are very slow ie they take about 30 seconds to 90 seconds to load.**

**The steps taken for generating the reports are**

1. Retrieve data rows in the data range selected by user. (query optimized to leave out irrelevant rows).
2. We have to do some complex calculations on each row in the data range user selects and 
   then decide if these rows are to be used in the report.
3. If they are to be used then further processing is done to generate results from data.

The **report generation is slow due to the "Step 2"** where we have to do some complex calculations to each relevant row in the data range selected by user. For example, if the user wants to generate a monthly report processing has to be done on around 600k rows.

**Now this report can be made faster if I can store the relevant rows to be used in step 3 in a "selected_events" table.**

After a user accesses the report the first time then the rows selected after step 2 can be stored in "selected_events" table.
So from second time the report will work faster.

**Now my questions are**

1. Will this not break 3NF?
2. Storing duplicate rows in another table for faster reports, is this an acceptable way?
3. Have anyone else done something like this and does it have any pitfalls?
4. What other steps are taken in large projects to overcome such issues?

**PS The data in event table is never updated after insertion. So the issue of updation not reflecting in duplicate table does not rise.**

Comment: At least data aggregation (for example storing calculated monthly figures) is quite normal for reporting purposes. Creating a cache based in previously executed report sounds quite more complex. not sure if it will be any better. I don't think we can give you any acceptance on anything, and pitfalls or steps in large projects are too broad for this site.

Comment: @JamesZ  I pin pointed the the issue, specified the exact step where the issue is,and also put a solution that could resolve the issue . I am not asking any general advise. I am asking what people do when faced with a situation like this. Is the solution I found used in other projects. I spent a fair amount of time googling and put the question on SO,  so that people who have more experience working with multiple projects can share their expertise.